# Getting XML File Into Parse.Com Class

Tags: ios, json, xml, parse-platform

I am trying to take a directory that is currently an RSS in XML format, and upload it as a class into Parse.com.  The structure of the XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss xmlns:itunes="http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd" version="2.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <channel>
        <atom:link rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" href="http://www.316apps.com/NewallaSermons/Directory.xml" />
        <lastBuildDate>Thu, 16 Aug 2012 09:26:14 -0500</lastBuildDate>
        <title>Newalla Church of Christ Directory</title>
        <description><![CDATA[Directory of Members for Newalla Church of Christ]]></description>

        <language>en</language>
        <copyright>2012 Newalla Church of Christ</copyright>

        <item>
            <title>Last Name</title>
            <description>First Name</description>
            <author>Address</author>
            <comments>Phone Number</comments>
            <link></link>
<pubDate>Sun, 09 Sep 2012 18:00:00 -0500</pubDate>
        </item>
        <item>
            <title>Another Last Name</title>
            <description>Another First Name</description>
            <author>Another Address</author>
            <comments>Another Phone Number</comments>
            <link></link>
<pubDate>Sun, 09 Sep 2011 18:00:00 -0500</pubDate>
        </item>

    </channel>
</rss>
```

Parse.com allows importing of JSON or CSV Files.  I have used an online converter for the JSON file, but when I import it, everything comes out as one row in the Parse table, instead of one row for each item.  It basically puts all after results into one line.  Suggestions?

The format of my JSON is:

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "rss": {
                "channel": {
                    "link": [
                        {
                            "_rel": "self",
                            "_type": "application/rss+xml",
                            "_href": "http://www.316apps.com/NewallaSermons/Directory.xml",
                            "__prefix": "atom"
                        },
                        "http://www.316apps.com"
                    ],
                    "lastBuildDate": "Thu, 16 Aug 2012 09:26:14 -0500",
                    "title": "Newalla Church of Christ Directory",
                    "author": {
                        "__prefix": "itunes",
                        "__text": "Newalla Church of Christ"
                    },
                    "generator": "Podcast Maker v1.4.1 - http://www.lemonzdream.com/podcastmaker",
                    "description": {
                        "__cdata": "Directory of Members for Newalla Church of Christ"
                    },
                    "summary": {
                        "__prefix": "itunes",
                        "__text": "Directory of Members for Newalla Church of Christ"
                    },
                    "language": "en",
                    "copyright": "2012 Newalla Church of Christ",
                    "item": [
                        {
                            "title": "First Name",
                            "description": "Last Name",
                            "author": "Address",
                            "comments": "Phone",
                            "link": "",
                            "pubDate": "Sun, 09 Sep 2012 18:00:00 -0500"
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "Another Last Name",
                            "description": "Another First",
                            "author": "Another Address",
                            "comments": "Another Phone",
                            "link": "",
                            "pubDate": "Sun, 09 Sep 2011 18:00:00 -0500"
                        },

                "_xmlns:itunes": "http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd",
                "_xmlns:atom": "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom",
                "_version": "2.0"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse is only interested in the objects itself, my guess is you will have to manually edit your JSON in TextEdit or something similar. Which could take just as long as manually creating the objects in the console yourself.

So if you just want all the books as objects you can simply erase the erroneous text and just leave:

```
{"results" : [
    {
        "title": "First Name",
        "description": "Last Name",
        "author": "Address",
        "comments": "Phone",
        "link": "",
        "pubDate": "Sun, 09 Sep 2012 18:00:00 -0500"
    },
    {
        "title": "Another First Name",
        "description": "Another Last Name",
        "author": "Another Address",
        "comments": "Another Phone",
        "link": "",
        "pubDate": "Sun, 09 Sep 2012 18:00:00 -0500"
    }
]}
```